# bootstrap modal is not working. the modal pop in hidden mode

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

i need to pop up a modal when click on a button. the modal is showing but is in hidden mode please look at the below image[image]

```
<script>
$('.searhBtn').click(function(e) {
    $('#modalSeach').modal('show');
});
</script>


    <div class="modal fade" id="modalSeach" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true" >

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3> Conformation </h3>
            </div>                
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    Do you want to ?
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="submit" name="permissions_submit" id="proceed" 
                autofocus="autofocus" >Proceed</button>
                <!--id="permissions_submit"-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your full code

Comment: @Learner in which place i have to put above line. in the inline style tag

Comment: @Learner i have tried it's not working. but i have other pages on those pages the modal is working fine ... i think there is any conflict in this page

Comment: ok, any way thank for your contribution

Comment: @Learner do you want to see the css and js files too..!

Comment: Something must be wrong with your css files. This one works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/8fpqxp9m/

Comment: @DDan i just try the **z-index** property  in side the click event now it is work

Comment: @Learner you have told me to call the z-index inside the css it was not work but i just tried with jquery like you said **$('#modalSeach').css('z-index', '9999999');** now it is working fine.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct.

HTML and script with css and js links:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<button class='searhBtn'> PRESS </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalSeach" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true" >

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3> Conformation </h3>
            </div>                
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    Do you want to ?
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="submit" name="permissions_submit" id="proceed" 
                autofocus="autofocus" >Proceed</button>
                <!--id="permissions_submit"-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script> 
    $('.searhBtn').click(function(e) {
        $('#modalSeach').modal('show');
    });  
</script>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/8fpqxp9m/